# How to store users API key and token using a command line tool

Tags: command-line, oauth, access-token

I'm developing a command line tool to help me make changes to a few resources without having to leave the terminal. The API I'm working with uses OAuth 2.0 and requires both an `API token` and `API key` in order to make requests. I'm wondering how I'll store both the `token` and `key` once I have obtained them without compromising their security. Could I store them in a file and just have the user use the `root` password in order to access it?

Comment: Please See This Link  https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

Comment: But what if I'm working with an Api that doesn't support personal access tokens?

Comment: please see on personal access tokens create on this link https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/publish/command-line

Comment: @beego I am working on a similar product and was running into the same problem, were you able to figure out a way to securely store the token on the CLI side securely?